# Can't figure out how $\sin\left(\tan^{-1}(x)\right)=\frac{x}{\sqrt {x^2+1}}$

Tags: calculus, inverse-function

Simplify the expression
$$\sin\left(\tan^{-1}(x)\right)$$
Using a triangle with an angle $\theta$, opposite  is x and adjacent is 1 meaning the hypo. is ${\sqrt {x^2+1}}$

Now because the problem has sin after the $\tan^{-1}(x)$ that means that the opp. being x, is put on top of the hypo. giving us the answer, but I feel like I'm missing something because I haven't incorporated the $\tan^{-1}x$

Comment: Have you drawn the picture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\tan^{-1}x=y\implies x=\tan y$ and $-\dfrac\pi2<y<\dfrac\pi2$ using [Principal values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values)

$\implies\cos y>0,\cos y=+\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+\tan^2y}}=?$

$\sin y=\cos y\cdot\tan y=?$

Comment: where'd you get the cos y from?

Comment: @EricBrown, $$\sec^2y-\tan^2y=?$$

Answer (score 4):

You're thinking about it just right.  $\tan^{-1}(x)$ is the angle whose tangent is $x$.  So draw a right triangle and put $\tan^{-1}(x)$ in a corner angle.  Since the tangent of that angle is $x$, the opposite side divided by the adjacent side must be $x$: the easiest choice is $x$ (opposite side) and $1$ (adjacent side) (though you could choose $1$ and $1/x$, or $\sqrt{x}$ and $1/\sqrt{x}$, or whatever you like with the right ratio).  Then the hypotenuse is $\sqrt{1+x^2}$, and the sine of your angle, being the opposite side divided by the hypotenuse, is $x/\sqrt{1+x^2}$.

Comment: Right. Just how I’d do it.

Comment: So replace $\theta$ with $\tan^{-1}(x)$?

Answer (score 0):

A solution with differential equations: let $f(x):=\sin(\tan^{-1} (x))$ and $g(x):= \frac{x}{\sqrt {x^2+1}}.$

Then it is easy to see that $f$ and $g$ are solutions of the second order intial value problem

$$(1+x^2)^2y''+2x(1+x^2)y'+y=0, \quad y(0)=0, \quad y'(0)=1$$

on $ \mathbb R.$

But this intial value problem has a unique solution on $ \mathbb R, $ thus $f=g$ on $ \mathbb R.$